# See what changed inside TextArea with on change listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, diff

I need a textbox, where everytime the text changes, I know what exactly has changed. I'm currently using a JQuery's listener for changes in my input element, and what I do is:

1. When the text changes
2. Get the text from the box a1 and compare to what I have in box a2.
3. If there are changes, log them into output textarea

Here is a Sample https://codepen.io/nikolaevra/pen/eeWWbo

I'm currently using the following diff library https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff, and it has O(NM) efficiency, which is a lot.

Is there a way to get the exact change that was made to the textarea using JQuery or anything like that? For example, if I had `test` in both a1 and a2 and then changed a1 to be `testing`, I want to see `ing` as the change that was made.

**EDIT:**
I tried playing around with the method a little bit and this is one problem that I found. When I run `diff = "testing".replace("test",'');` => `ing` just as required, but when I try `diff = "testing a potato cannon".replace("testing potato cannon",'');` => `testing a potato cannon`, where I only changed one character. This is a lot of overhead that I wanted to avoid. In that case, I would only want to know where the value has been changed and what it has been changed to. Not the entire tail of the string.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you've made so far?

Comment: @eeya look at the link in the post, `Here is a Sample`

Comment: I don't know how to produce the desired output efficiently, but note that using `.replace()` doesn't even come close to solving the problem because it doesn't handle changes in the middle of the string, or where a single edit changed more than one part of the string, or where the edit removed part of the string.

Comment: Calculating a proper delta between values is probably more resource-intensive than listening to all the possible events that can modify a textarea. Neither are particularly simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that what you have in string `a1` is the constant text and that what you have in string `a2` is where you make changes.

let's just say that the value in `a1` is `"test"`;

Try this for your JavaScript:

```
var constValue = $('#a1').val();
$('#a2').change(function() {
    var changingValue = $('a2').val();                   // say the value entered is "testing"
    console.log(changingValue.replace(constValue, '');   // gives you "ing"
}
```

This will give you the changed/entered (newly) value in string `a2` and log it to your console.

The logic you use here is simple:

> Read the value from string `a2` and use the value in `a1` to replace (if exists) in string `a2`, hence giving you the changed value. You need not use any libraries for this. JavaScript gives you this function called `replace`.

Do let me know if any more queries.

Comment: please see the edit that I added to my question. `.replace()` almost works, but it introduces a lot of overhead, when the change that was made is in the middle of the string.

Comment: Did u try converting your entire string in both cases to an array and then comparing individual values? It seems like a long process but will help you achieve what you are trying now.

Comment: What if the change removed part of the string, or was is in the middle of the existing string, or if a single edit changes more than one part of the string?

Comment: That was the initial idea, but the procedure will take O(NM), which is what the diff algorithm currently gives me. Also I was hoping for an overall simpler solution, but maybe that's the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

nikolaevra, have you tried using javascript's replace method? e.g diff = [value of a1].replace([value of a2],'');

Comment: This sounds cool, but my main goal is to track changes. How i mentioned in the example, if the original text is `test` and you change it to `testing`, i want to see that added `ing` as the change

Comment: yes, if the value of a1 and a2 is 'test' initially and if you then change the value of a1 to 'testing', then the above replace method would give you the exact diff i.e 'ing'

Comment: Ok, I tried playing around with the method a little bit and this is one problem that I found. When I run `diff = "testing".replace("test",'');` => `ing` just as required, but when I try `diff = "testing a potato cannon".replace("testing potato cannon",'');` => `testing a potato cannon`, where I only changed one character. Probably the question was not clear enough, im going to update it accordingly.

Comment: What if the change removed part of the string, or was is in the middle of the existing string, or if a single edit changes more than one part of the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to achive what you are looking for :

```
function getDifference(a, b)
{
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var result = "";

  while (j < b.length)
  {
    if (a[i] != b[j] || i == a.length)
        result += b[j];
    else
        i++;
    j++;
  }
  return result;
 }
```

Then you need to make a method to get the values from your textboxs and use it in your button onclick event, I used javascript, you can use jquery if you want :

```
function findDiff(){
  var b1=  document.getElementById("b1").value;//sky is blue
  var b2= document.getElementById("b2").value;//sky is red
  document.getElementById("result").value=getDifference(b1,b2);//red
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eu2kvfxo/

Answer (score 0):

**i hope this code will help you**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var arr_text1 = new Array();
           var arr_text2 = new Array();
           var i=0;
           var text2nw="";
           $('#a2').on('input',function () {
               arr_text1 = $("#a1").val().split('');
               arr_text2 = $("#a2").val().split('');
               if (arr_text1[i] == arr_text2[i]) {
                              }
               else {
                   $('#output').val($("#a2").val().replace($("#a1").val(), ""));
                  // $('#output').val(text2nw);
               }
               if ($("#a2").val() != '') {
                   i++;
               }
               else {
                   i = 0;
                   $('#output').val('');
               }
           });
       });
   </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>This is the original text:</p>
    <textarea id="a1" rows="4" cols="50" type="text"></textarea>

    <p>Change Text to something else here:</p>
    <textarea id="a2" rows="4" cols="50" type="text"></textarea>

    <p id="title">This are the changes that you made:</p>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="output" for="title"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```